# Cannot find subfile with subdirectory

Tags: errors, texshop, subfiles

I want to include a subfile in the main document. I put a subfile in a different directory called "sections" , but the main.tex can’t find it.  Error File 'section/chapter I.tex' not found.

[image]

here's my code of main.tex:

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{book}

%package
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[french]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{subfiles} 


%french typography
\AddThinSpaceBeforeFootnotes    

%setting
\parindent=2cm 

%preamble
\author{XXXX}
\title{XXXX}
\date{17/4/2018}

%content
\begin{document}

\maketitle
XXXX

\subfile{sections/chapter I}

\end{document}
```

now, here's my code of chapter I.tex:

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}

\begin{document}

\section{Intro}
this is XXXX.

\end{document}
```

when I run chapter I.tex, it's ok, but the main.tex just cannot find it.

Comment: Can you try without spaces in your file name? Or with `\subfile{./sections/chapter I}`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem is just due to spaces in file names and solved in comments.

Comment: You could also try adding quotes around the file name.